# EMC AVAMAR Compatibility with SQL Server 2008 R2 in Active/Passive Clustered Mode

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-cluster

We are currently using EMC AVAMAR as part of our backup policy for backing up all our servers. We also have a SQL Server 2008 R2 active/passive setup.

Does anyone know if EMC AVAMAR is compatible in backing up SQL databases that are in an active/passive SQL Server instance?

Comment: Have you considered just reading it up in the documentation? Or the marketing material? This sounds like a super simply question to answer for me.

Comment: Thanks, I have but it is not entirely clear. They say they support SQL but not specific to Active/Passive mode.

Comment: I can vouch for the unclear nature of the EMC/Avamar documentation.  Personally, when I run into these kind of problems, I call the toll-free support number so that the company which couldn't be bothered to put out good documentation gets to pay for the privilege of answering my question.  I'd definitely recommend calling EMC and asking.